# How to copy iTunes files as raw wav files

Tags: bash, terminal, itunes, finder

I have converted a bunch of mp3 and m4a files in iTunes to wav files, and am now trying to put all the wav files into a separate directory.

Currently, I am doing

```
find Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/folder/ -name 
'*.wav' -exec cp {} Documents/folder \;
```

However, this creates a TextEdit document which opens up iTunes. I want to know if there is a way to have a folder in Documents which has all of the converted wav files without the apparent iTunes association

Comment: Try with single quotes around {}, like so `'{}'`.

Comment: Still results in a file which opens iTunes

Comment: Does this work: `find "~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/folder/" -name '*.wav' -execdir cp '{}' "~/Documents/folder" \;`

Comment: How about `cp Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/folder/*.wav Documents/folder`?